# Get mouse location during mouse down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I continuously get the position of the mouse whilst its button is being held down?

I know I can do:

```
<element onclick="functionName(event)"></element>
<script>
function functionName(e){
e.pageX
e.pageY
//do stuff
}
</script>
```

and I know you can use the onmousedown event, but how would I continuously get the position while the button is still held down?

Oddly I couldn't find this anywhere I looked.

Comment: What do you mean by *"continuous"*? Try `onmouseover`.

Comment: As the mouse moves, I want to update the position continuously, but I want the mouse to be being clicked, not hovering over the element..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Anyway, I'd suggest using `mousemove` event with check if `which` event property equals `1` (i.e. left mouse button pressed):

```
$("element").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
        console.log(e.pageX + " / " + e.pageY);
    }
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HBZBQ/

Comment: `e.which == 1` is pure genius. Why didn't I think of this!

Comment: neat solution!!

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uXqB3/) is a JSFiddle for you. You need to store the state of the mouse button in a variable.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        $(this).data('mousedown', true);
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        $(this).data('mousedown', false);
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if($(this).data('mousedown')) {
            $('body').text('X: ' + e.pageX + ', Y: ' + e.pageY);
        }
    });
});​
```

Here, I'm storing the mouse button's up or down state in `document` using `$(document).data()`. I could have used a global variable, but storing it this way makes the code a little cleaner.

In your `$.mousemove()` function, only do what you want if the mouse is down. In the code above, I'm simply printing the mouse's position.

Comment: Nice! In IE, the accepted answer changes the values onmouseover without the mousedown event. This one is working fine in every browser that I tried! Thanks!